# Can't get HTML5 History API to work properly

Tags: jquery, html

Well, im trying to make html5 history api working properly (without the page reloading)

But I can't find where im going wrong in the middle of the path.

www2.madeinweb.com.br/inovacao/transitions/

This is my demo page rolling on.

```
$(function() {
    $(".external").click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(body).load(href);
        history.pushState( null, null, href );
        return false
    });

    $( window ).bind( "popstate", function( e ) {
        var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;
        alert( returnLocation.href );
    });
});
```

This is the script im working with right now. Im not sure about the load method that im using now. Is this the best workaround for it?

Thanks.